# Rename a set of tables with a pl/sql script

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

i need to rename a bunch of tables on a schema and since there's a lot of them i'd need a proper script but i'm not really proficient in PL/SQL...
The rule is that i need to rename all tables that end up with the string "_ARC"
removing that string

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
  for i in (select t.TABLE_NAME as old_name
                  ,substr (t.TABLE_NAME,1,length(t.TABLE_NAME)-4) as new_name
            from user_tables t
            where t.TABLE_NAME like '%\_ARC' escape '\')
    loop
      execute immediate 'rename '||i.old_name||' to '||i.new_name;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Reminder: if still on Oracle 9, you would have to switch that to the 'alter table current_table_name rename to new_table_name' syntax.